# ADB Doesn't recognize Nexus S in Mac 10.6

Tags: android, macos, adb

I just bought the Nexus S with the android version 2.3.3, which I update it to 2.3.4. I use to develop my android apps in my Mac but when i tried to connect my new Nexus S with the ADB it wasn't recognized. Though the ADB worked pretty well with pass android devices.

Moreover, I connected my Nexus S with the ADB under my Linux machine and then worked as a charm.

Any suggestions on how to make the nexus s be recognized to the ADB of my Mac OS X?

EDIT:

I Found the Answer Here:
http://bagosgiar.posterous.com/adb-doesnt-recognize-my-android-phone-under-m

:D

Comment: I think you have to install the USB driver, I know that happened to me on my windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have to install Google Usb Driver Package Revision 4. In Eclipse -> Android SDK Manager -> Available Packages -> Third party Add-ons.</strike> 
EDIT: My bad, it says on dev site: `Note: If you're developing on Mac OS X or Linux, then you do not need to install a USB driver`.

Comment: I am looking for it but it is not fetched in the list. Indeed it is installed Usb Driver Package Revision 2.

Comment: Then go to Installed Packages, at Usb Driver Package Revision 2 and update it.

Comment: And one more thing, make sure it is set on debugging mode. I'm sure it is, but check it anyway.

Comment: I've check it multiple times, but the problem still :(